# How to set hibernate.cfg.xml to work offline?

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate

I use standard  hibernate.cfg.xml file that start with :

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

and add hibernate3.jar to classpath by netbeans IDE .

who i set  hibernate.cfg.xml to use dtd file inside the  "hibernate.jar"  ?

Comment: Try this <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
    "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

Comment: no . i get this error: Nested exception: org.hibernate.HibernateException  ..... Could not parse configuration C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 6.0.26\bin\hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: where is your hibernate jar located? is it in the classpath? If you unzip the hibernate jar, you will find a copy of dtd there. Out idea is to point to that dtd in your cfg file. If your hibernate is in classpath, the dtd will also be in classpath. Can you find that dtd , get it's path and put that in your cfg file?

Comment: in netbeans IDE for set classpath i do -->1.Right-click my Project 2.Select Properties 3.On the left-hand side click Libraries 4.Under Compile tab - click Add library button and select HIbernate  .i unzip hibernate,jar , i find a "hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" there

Comment: I am not very hands on with netbeans. But you need to find out the physical location, where the hibernate jar resides and then unzip it and check.

Comment: i test this :<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "C:/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
and correct run .how set relative Relative address to use in my project location ?

Comment: It is good that the idea worked. Relative address can be achieved through the "classpath" option only. Maybe you need to google a bit about the correct classpath location of the dtd.

Comment: @amir2taghvaei: Did you find an answer to this ?